# Remapped CapsLock key is ignored (set by XKBOPTIONS in /etc/default/keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb, capslock

I tried to follow https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey which says this can be done this way:

> On Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint etc.)
>
> To make Caps Lock another Ctrl key, edit the file
>   **/etc/default/keyboard** and change the line which
>   reads
>
> ```
>  XKBOPTIONS=""
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
>  XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"      #
> Some people prefer "ctrl:swapcaps"
> ```
>
> and then
>   run:
>
> ```
>  $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh console-setup
> ```

After I've done this if I click on "Show keyboard layout" it looks like it works:
[image: screenshots]
but it actually doesn't, this remapped capslock key cannot be used in any combos, like Ctrl+A to select all, etc.

What is missing here to remap it properly?

Also I know about Gnome tweak tool, but it can only affect applications that run on top of Gnome, so anything running in Wine for example doesn't receive Ctrl key when I press CapsLock, and I need to do the remap globally. Like AutoHotkey on Windows can do, or like macOS can do with built in setting.

Also tried:

- editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` to let `<CAPS>` have the same number as `<LCTL>`  (`setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` says that these keycodes are being used if I understand it correctly)
- editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` (changing *that line* to `key <LCTL> {    [ Control_L     ]   };`)

both attempts did not work at all.
P.S. after each of these attempts I also did a complete reboot

Complete output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru,us
variant:    ,,
options:    grp_led:scroll
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
symbols:    pc+us+ru:2+us:3+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+us:3+inet(evdev)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Complete content of `/etc/default/keyboard` after editing:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll,ctrl:nocaps"
```

I have no idea what is "grp_led:scroll" so I thought it'd be safer to leave it there

Update:
Complete output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`:

```
['grp_led:scroll', 'ctrl:nocaps', 'grp:alt_shift_toggle']
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question again and show us the output of the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson done

Comment: Thanks. My thought was that there might be some conflict between the desktop settings and the system wide settings in `/etc/default/keyboard`, but I don't see such a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the correct solution, but it seems that the XKBOPTIONS and changes to files in xkb directory affect everything except Gnome, so if I use it **in addition** to gnome tweaks then it works in both situations.

Comment: That's probably it. Settings in Tweaks (i.e. the output from the command I asked you to show) overrides the system wide settings in `/etc/default/keyboard` as regards the desktop behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have to change it in gnome-tweaks for both your user and the root user.

```
sudo gnome-tweaks  # then set the capslock setting you want
gnome-tweaks  # do it again
```

This is because the user setting will override the root settings.

Tested in ubuntu 20.04

Thanks to user @Gunnar-Hjalmarsson for the clue that lead to me finding this.